# kendo grid dropdownlist editor template blank after postback

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

On Asp.Net MVC page, grid has two column of drop down editor template.

On Load, it works fine. I can see the dropdown populated with values.

After postback, the drop down list is getting empty/blank.

Editor template are placed under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates.

How to retain values dropdown values after postback?

Comment: Adding some code to your question would be really helpful.

Comment: Or else you can save `dataSource` and again initialize the dropdownlist with the previous `dataSource`. Use this if nothing is working but I don't recommend it. But for another solution add some code so that we can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data for Editor template comes from view data. So I refilled the view data info on the POST method.